# Which paradigm or pattern to use for creating a wrapper over an API with python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, oop, interface, architecture

I want to create a library with python that uses different services from aws to access my data. The data can come from s3-bucket(AWS) with boto3 library, or via services from aws (like AWS Athena, or maybe dynamodb or even rds)...

This all should be done with python. I cannot decide if I should go for an object-oriented approach for defining interfaces(how should I do that abc library=)?) or go for a functional approach(overwrite the functions via a config file)?

I thought of using my library as an abstract class -> defining the methods, and then create subclasses inheriting and implementing the defined methods.

But what happens if I want e.g a `read_customer_data()` method to use s3 as an underlying data source, and `read_organisation_data()` from dynamodb. In this case, I couldn't change the underlying class. So what to do, if I want to be flexible in using different data sources.

For me, it seems like I can't use one interface for this approach since it can happen that I need two different subclasses in one application